# subprocess.call doesn't run as expected

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a simple script, to call a sql script from python

```
subprocess.call([
    'sqlcmd',
    '-S', 'server_name',
    '-d', 'db name'
    '-i', r'path to the script + script name'
    ])
```

The python script runs without errors, but never calls the sql script. I can run the sql script through command line `sqlcmd "path to the script + script name"` and it works as expected.

I can call a stored procedure using the `subprocess` module with no problem,

```
subprocess.Popen([
        'sqlcmd',
        '-S', 'server_name',
        '-d', 'db name'
        '-Q', 'exec stored procedure'
    ])
```

but calling a separate script gives no results. I have tried including `shell = True` or use `Popen` but nothing changes.

To do more testing I have created a test script that just returns the name of the current database. I ran it through command line with no problems 
`sqlcmd -S server_name -d db_name -i "directory/test1.sql"`, getting the expected result. I have tried to run it with `subprocess` module and got my issue again, I've tried `subprocess.call_check` and got an error stating `exit status 1`. So the script runs with command line, but doesn't with `subprocess` module .

Comment: What *does* happen? Do you get an error? Or does it simply do nothing? Are you certain the argument you're passing to `-i` is correct? Have you checked?

Comment: if I put `print` statements before and after the subprocess.call I get both statements printed, no errors. The argument in `-i` is correct because when I run exactly same argument through command line `sqlcmd 'path to the script + script name'` I get the script to run. If the argument in `-i` was incorrect I would get an error.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was with directories for sql script and the python script, even though I was specifying the full path for the sql script. They were on separate discs, and I was keep getting `non-zero exit status 1` when I would use `subprocess.call_check()`. I've put both scripts in the same location and the issue is gone.